# OracleSolaris 11.2 - delete a directory which is mount point

Tags: filesystems, solaris, opensolaris

I removed a user from the syste, with `userdel -r user` however it still keeps its homedirectory `/export/home/user`, although the contents has been removed.

The directory is mounted, but I don't know how I can permanently unmount it, also what is the *solaris-way* to remove user accounts including their $HOMES?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a dedicated zfs file system was created for that user, you should be able to delete it with:

```
zfs destroy rpool/export/home/user
```

Comment: @jilliagre, I'm not sure if 'user' has created ZFS file system. I created that user during installation, later changed its name with usermod, that worked fine, however it left the homedir. Now this partition stays mounted:

**$ mount | grep user
/export/home/user on rpool/export/home/user read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/nonbmand/exec/xattr/atime/dev=45d0007**


BTW, 'zfs delete' reports unknown command.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo, that should be `zfs destroy ...`. That file system was automatically created by the installer/useradd, not by the user.